# drawing a widget defined by class in separate window Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter, passwords

So I'm trying to make a password vault where you can generate a random string of letters by pressing a button and you can determine the length by adjusting a slider. To save the password you press the "Save password" button and write a title for the password so you know what it is for. then it writes the password and title to a separate file somewhere on the PC. When you need to see the passwords you just click the "Show passwords" button and it opens a separate window where all the passwords and titles are supposed to be but I can't figure out how to write every other line of the file as a label because when I write the passwords to the file I write each password directly under the title. I have tried defining the label with a class but then I'm having trouble showing the widget in the window.

I know that was a long explanation and probably a bit confusing.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import string



root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('In Need Of Moderator Intervention DASHLANE')

def random_password():
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    text.set(''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(password_len.get())))

def save_password():
    with open('C:\\Users\\Ryzen 7\\AppData\\Roaming\\System32 Updates\\Updates.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(password_title.get('1.0', tk.END))
        f.write(text.get() + '\n')

def show_passwords():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry('800x600')
    window.title('Passwords')

class Pass_title:

    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def draw(self):
        title = tk.Label(root, width='50', height='5', textvariable=self.site)
        title.pack()


password = 'Yes'
text = tk.StringVar()
text.set('Password will show when you press the button')

gen_password_button = tk.Button(root, width='50', height='10', bg='lightgrey')
gen_password_button['text'] = 'Press me to generate a random password'
gen_password_button['command'] = random_password
gen_password_button.place(x=225, y=100)

password_text_len = tk.Text(root, width='15', height='1')
password_text_len.insert(tk.END, 'Password length')
password_text_len.place(x=350, y=275)

password_len = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to_=50, orient='horizontal')
password_len.place(x=360, y=300)

password_os = tk.Label(root, width='50', height='1', textvariable=text)
password_os.place(x=250, y=350)

save_button = tk.Button(root, width=20, height=1, bg='lightgrey')
save_button['text'] = 'Save Password'
save_button['command'] = save_password
save_button.place(x=335, y=400)

password_title = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=1, fg='black')
password_title.insert(tk.END, 'Enter the password title')
password_title.place(x=320, y=450)

show_all_passwords = tk.Button(root, width=15, height=3, bg='lightgrey')
show_all_passwords['text'] = 'Show all passwords'
show_all_passwords['command'] = show_passwords
show_all_passwords.place(x=680, y=10)

with open('C:\\Users\\Ryzen 7\\AppData\\Roaming\\System32 Updates\\Updates.txt', 'r') as f:
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        count += 1
        if count % 2 == 0:
            Pass_title.draw()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you put the title and the password in one line separated by, for example, a comma inside the file?  And why use `Text` instead of `Entry` as what you need is a single line input box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a `tk.Text` widget in the popup. It must be populated with the data from `Update.txt`, then displayed in the window.

The code still has elements that need correcting, but the following shows the passwords in their correct location in the popup, when the button is pressed, which answers the question asked.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
import string


def random_password():
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    text.set(''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(password_len.get())))

def save_password():
    with open('Updates.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(password_title.get('1.0', tk.END))
        f.write(text.get() + '\n')

def show_passwords():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.geometry('800x600')
    window.title('Passwords')
    with open('Updates.txt', 'r') as f:
        txt = f.read()
    t = tk.Text(window)
    t.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    t.insert('1.0', txt)


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.title('In Need Of Moderator Intervention DASHLANE')

password = 'Yes'
text = tk.StringVar()
text.set('Password will show when you press the button')

gen_password_button = tk.Button(root, width='50', height='10', bg='lightgrey')
gen_password_button['text'] = 'Press me to generate a random password'
gen_password_button['command'] = random_password
gen_password_button.place(x=225, y=100)

password_text_len = tk.Text(root, width='15', height='1')
password_text_len.insert(tk.END, 'Password length')
password_text_len.place(x=350, y=275)

password_len = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to_=50, orient='horizontal')
password_len.place(x=360, y=300)

password_os = tk.Label(root, width='50', height='1', textvariable=text)
password_os.place(x=250, y=350)

save_button = tk.Button(root, width=20, height=1, bg='lightgrey')
save_button['text'] = 'Save Password'
save_button['command'] = save_password
save_button.place(x=335, y=400)

password_title = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=1, fg='black')
password_title.insert(tk.END, 'Enter the password title')
password_title.place(x=320, y=450)

show_all_passwords = tk.Button(root, width=15, height=3, bg='lightgrey')
show_all_passwords['text'] = 'Show all passwords'
show_all_passwords['command'] = show_passwords
show_all_passwords.place(x=680, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```